# Sprint Meetings - What to talk about

Tags: agile, scrum, sprint

In work we have just started using the Scrum methodology, it is working well but I have a question on the daily sprint meetings.

We set aside 15 minutes for the meeting (between the three devs and the scrum master if we think he is needed) but I have found that we have normally finished by 5 minutes.

This might be because we have said all that needs to be said but I was wondering what people tend to talk about in them, in case we are missing something.

For the record we normally update each other on current objective, troublesome previous objectives and plans for the rest of the day (including if we will not be available on that project).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *intent* of the stand-up meeting is to keep all of the team members informed of recent progress and any impediments that may hinder progress. If it only takes your team 5 minutes to accomplish that goal, then 5 minutes is the proper time and you shouldn't worry too much about it.

I tend to stick pretty much to the classic:

- What I have accomplished since the last stand-up
- What I'll be doing until the next stand-up
- Any issues that I think might keep me from getting my tasks done

but if I need to I'll add

- Anything new I've learned (about the system / environment) that I think the team needs to know
- Quick thank-you acknowledgements for team-members who have helped me out in a significant way

The important thing is to share important and timely information quickly and concisely. If that's being accomplished, then the exact time-frame is secondary.

Answer (score 2):

The Scrum Master ensure that the process (Scrum) is properly implemented. He is mandatory in daily stand ups (it's how they are called).

15 minutes is OK for a team of 5 (3 minutes per team member). If you don't speak more than 1 minutes, it looks like a smell to me. Could you check you respect [these rules](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/scrum/daily-scrum)?

Comment: In my team's standup we often speak less than a minute. To me, that's a Good Thing. It means you are on track, there are no impediments, and it's clear what you are working on.

Comment: You can say alot in 1 minute.  I think time is more a guideline and can point out the content delivery needs possible tweaking.  It's the content of the delivery that's the more important aspect not the time it takes IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

(these meetings are usually called daily **scrums** or "daily standup meetings".  The word "sprint" refers to the iteration, which is typically between 1 and 4 weeks long.)

**If you're done in 5 minutes, that's great!** (of course, I assume that you covered the required three questions in those five minutes.)

One of the things new scrum teams struggle with is that these meetings run much longer than 15 minutes and people deviate from the agenda to discuss requirements, design, prioritization, etc.  But it looks like you've mastered this element of scrum already.

Answer (score 0):

> Betwen 3 devs and the scrum master if we think he is needed.

Maybe you have a small number of people attending the meeting.
Or does anyone give 'No update'?? kidding.

I am using scrum as well. we have approximately 13~15 people attending on the daily stand up meeting. What I usually report are

1. Any QA delivery(yesterday and today..) with user story
2. If all the user story delivered to QA, I make sure to say "All the user stories are delivered to QA"
3. If I am fixing the bug, I report how many bugs were fixed yesterday and how many remains..

So, we have 2 weeks sprint. For the first week, I usually talk about user story delivery and the second week is all about bug fix~~

Comment: We are a small elite band of developers! Just the three of us working on one sprint at a time.